# Face Detection OpenCV Python GUI

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, opencv, tkinter

I'm new in the Python GUI world. I'm developing a Python project to detect faces in a webcam and take a picture of the face, that part is already set up. I've been searching and testing codes for the GUI part, I tried with PyQt and PySide but I didn't have succed. I found a code from Adrian at PyImageSearch which have a frame for the webcam and a button to capture the image and use Tkinter for the GUI.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk
import Tkinter as tki
import threading
import datetime
import imutils
import cv2
import os

class PhotoBoothApp:
  def __init__(self, vs, outputPath):
    # store the video stream object and output path, then initialize
    # the most recently read frame, thread for reading frames, and
    # the thread stop event
    self.vs = vs
    self.outputPath = outputPath
    self.frame = None
    self.thread = None
    self.stopEvent = None

    # initialize the root window and image panel
    self.root = tki.Tk()
    self.panel = None

    # create a button, that when pressed, will take the current
    # frame and save it to file
    btn = tki.Button(self.root, text="Snapshot!",
        command=self.takeSnapshot)
    btn.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes", padx=10,
        pady=10)

    # start a thread that constantly pools the video sensor for
    # the most recently read frame
    self.stopEvent = threading.Event()
    self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.videoLoop, args=())
    self.thread.start()

    # set a callback to handle when the window is closed
    self.root.wm_title("PyImageSearch PhotoBooth")
    self.root.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.onClose)

  def videoLoop(self):
    # DISCLAIMER:
    # I'm not a GUI developer, nor do I even pretend to be. This
    # try/except statement is a pretty ugly hack to get around
    # a RunTime error that Tkinter throws due to threading
    try:
        # keep looping over frames until we are instructed to stop
        while not self.stopEvent.is_set():
            # grab the frame from the video stream and resize it to
            # have a maximum width of 300 pixels
            self.frame = self.vs.read()
            self.frame = imutils.resize(self.frame, width=300)

            # OpenCV represents images in BGR order; however PIL
            # represents images in RGB order, so we need to swap
            # the channels, then convert to PIL and ImageTk format
            image = cv2.cvtColor(self.frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            image = Image.fromarray(image)
            image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

            # if the panel is not None, we need to initialize it
            if self.panel is None:
                self.panel = tki.Label(image=image)
                self.panel.image = image
                self.panel.pack(side="left", padx=10, pady=10)

            # otherwise, simply update the panel
            else:
                self.panel.configure(image=image)
                self.panel.image = image

    except RuntimeError, e:
        print("[INFO] caught a RuntimeError")

  def takeSnapshot(self):
    # grab the current timestamp and use it to construct the
    # output path
    ts = datetime.datetime.now()
    filename = "{}.jpg".format(ts.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"))
    p = os.path.sep.join((self.outputPath, filename))

    # save the file
    cv2.imwrite(p, self.frame.copy())
    print("[INFO] saved {}".format(filename))

  def onClose(self):
    # set the stop event, cleanup the camera, and allow the rest of
    # the quit process to continue
    print("[INFO] closing...")
    self.stopEvent.set()
    self.vs.stop()
    self.root.quit()
```

Now the part for the detection face I think it should go in the videoLoop function and I added the face detection code to it so the function looks like this

```
try:
        # keep looping over frames until we are instructed to stop
        while not self.stopEvent.is_set():
            # grab the frame from the video stream and resize it to
            # have a maximum width of 300 pixels
            self.frame = self.vs.read()
            self.frame = imutils.resize(self.frame, width=300)

            # OpenCV represents images in BGR order; however PIL
            # represents images in RGB order, so we need to swap
            # the channels, then convert to PIL and ImageTk format
            detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier("C:\Proyectos\Python\GUI\tkinter-photo-booth\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
            image = cv2.cvtColor(self.frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)


            # load the cat detector Haar cascade, then detect cat faces
            # in the input image

            rects = detector.detectMultiScale(image, scaleFactor=1.5,
                minNeighbors=5, minSize=(30, 30))
            # loop over the cat faces and draw a rectangle surrounding each
            for (i, (x, y, w, h)) in rects:
                cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
            image = Image.fromarray(image)
            image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

            # if the panel is not None, we need to initialize it
            if self.panel is None:
                self.panel = tki.Label(image=image)
                self.panel.image = image
                self.panel.pack(side="left", padx=10, pady=10)

            # otherwise, simply update the panel
            else:
                self.panel.configure(image=image)
                self.panel.image = image
```

But when I run the code, the rectangles to frame the face doesn't appear. I don't really know if the code to detect faces should go in the voidLoop function or if it should go in the snapshot function. I've already ask to Adrian in his webpage but I'm searching for extra help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried decreasing the scaleFactor and minNeighbors parameters at the detectMultiScale call? Maybe you are being too strict, and the detector is not finding anything. You could try with scaleFactor=1.2, minNeighbors=1, just to try, and then fine-tune it (because it will definetly slow down your code). Also, I would recommend adding a line after the detector printing len(rects), to see if it finds something. Otherwise, it's just a problem showing the rectangles in the image.

Comment: Hey caspillaga. I already tried decreasing the parameters but it didn't work. I will try adding the line after the detector. Thanks for your advice. I let you know what happen